# Get N recent objects from multiple models at one place in Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

I'm working on a project using Python(3.7) and Django(3) in Which I have created 4 models, for example, `A`, `B`, `C`, and `D`. All of these models are storing any kind of report. Now on the home page, I need to display 10 recent reports from all of these models.

how Can I achieve that?

> These models don't have any foreign Key to each other.

**From `models.py`:**

```
class DistributionReport(models.Model):
    RequestId = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=False, default=0)
    Currency = models.CharField(max_length=3, blank=False)
    Denomination = models.IntegerField(blank=False, default=0)decimal_places=2)
    date = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Distribution Report'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.RequestId


class ExpenditureReport(models.Model):
    RequestId = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=False, default=0)
    StaffExpenditure = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2)
    Month = models.IntegerField(blank=False, default=0)
    Quarter = models.IntegerField(blank=False, default=0)
    Year = models.IntegerField(blank=False, default=0)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Expenditure Report'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.RequestId


class StorageReport(models.Model):
    RequestId = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=False, default=0)
    Currency = models.CharField(max_length=5, blank=False)
    Denomination = models.IntegerField(blank=False, default=0)
    date = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Processing Report'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.RequestId


class AssetsReport(models.Model):
    RequestId = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=False, default=0)
    AssetClassificationId = models.IntegerField(blank=False, default=0)
    VaultCapacity = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    Year = models.IntegerField(blank=False, default=0)
    HalfOftheYear = models.IntegerField(blank=False, default=0)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Assets Report'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.RequestId
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
objects = Model.objects.filter(<some query>)[:10]
```

Comment: it's from single `Model` I need to query multiple models at once.

Comment: Could you show all your models? Or at least their important fields. Edit your question with it please.

Comment: I have added my `'models.py`

Comment: I've made a research and found out that you can't merge different models. You have to make something with foreign keys or save your reports in 5th model.